# How do I DKIM authenticate a domain with a cPanel server that does not host it?

Tags: email, authentication, cpanel, spam, dkim

- I have a domain 'example.com.au'
- 'example.com.au' is hosted on cPanel Server A
- I want to allow 'example.com.au' to be authenticated via DKIM to send mail via cPanel Server B
- 'example.com.au' does **not** have to be DKIM authenticated with cPanel Server A (this is not a question about different prefixes than 'default_')

What is the correct way to achieve this?

I had a thought that it might be to copy the DKIM record provided by Server B's WHM option 'Email Deliverability' and add it to 'example.com.au's DNS records, but I'm a bit lost with this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Send the e-mails from Server A via Server B, if Server B does the DKIM signature. That should work as you are using Server B like a e-mail proxy.

Problem in this case is: if server B is down, server A cannot send any mails anymore.

Better solution: Use a Mail-Gateway that does DKIM for you and both servers send the mails to the Mail-Gateway.

Or you have to use the same DKIM certificates on both servers.